# In how many ways can a subcommittee be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A committee has seven members, three of whom are male and four of whom are female.  In how many ways can a subcommittee  be selected if it is to consist of

1. three males
2. four females
3. two males and two females

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i have not tried it because , i am stack dont know where to start from please help. jose carlos

Comment: Please try again with my hints.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint: Since you are forming a subcommittee, the ordering of the members within the subcommittee does not matter.
>
> Now, you can apply unordered selection (i.e. selection where order does not matter) onto the members of the committee.

An example where the order of selection matters, would be to select a president, a vice-president and a secretary, instead of selecting a subcommittee of $3$ members.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is a positive integer, then the number $n!$, read "[$n$ factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)," is the product of the first $n$ positive integers.  By definition, $0! = 1$.

The number of subsets (unordered selections) of size $k$ of a set with $n$ elements is given by the formula
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
The expression $\binom{n}{k}$ is read "$n$ choose $k$."  See this page on [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) for more information.

In the first problem, select the subcommittee from among the male members of the committee.

In the second problem, select the subcommittee from among the female members of the committee.

In the third problem, select the male members of the subcommittee from among the male members of the committee and the female members of the subcommittee from the female members of the committee.  Then apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_principle).

The numbers in this problem are sufficiently small that you should be able to check your answers by simply listing all the possibilities.